# Why, when I run a TensorFlow model, does it only use CPU as a runtime?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

When I train a simple neural network and I check the GPU usage, I've noticed that my TensorFlow scripts was run in CPU. And this's my configuration :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqMcL.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A model needs to be "big enough" in order to profit from GPU acceleration, as training data needs to be transferred to the GPU, and new weights need to be downloaded from the GPU, and this overhead reduces the efficiency, making things slower.Thanks!